# Bring about racial justice

Tags: word-usage

> During this time,his efforts to bring ___ racial justice won him the support of both blacks and whites.
>   (A) up (B) about

Why is the answer not (B)？

Comment: Definitely should be (B).

Comment: To 'bring up racial justice' would mean to 'talk about it when it was a forbidden topic;' but not necessarily to make things better. 'Efforts to bring about racial justice' is the obvious choice, if that was his aim.

Comment: Either answer is could be correct without any context.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I will check out the answer again and  discuss with my teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer depends entirely on context.  Consider this:

> The young senator debated the older, more conservative politicians for several hours.  *During this time, his efforts to bring **up** racial justice won him the support of both blacks and whites.*

In this case, the phrase *bring up* means ***[to raise (a subject) for discussion; mention](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bring--up?s=t)*** (from Dictionary.com).  As an alternative, consider this:

> Having given up on the conservative politicians, the young senator fought hard for civil rights in congress.  *During this time, his efforts to bring **about** racial justice won him the support of both blacks and whites.*

Here the phrase *bring about* means ***[to cause to occur or exist](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bring--up?s=t)***.